# Can I assign MySQL fields to HTML elements with jQuery indexes?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Can I find the index of the element I want in jQuery and then request the row and assign fields relative to the index into the HTML elements?

Comment: yes. so start writing some code, and ask when you get stuck

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but if I understood you correctly: Yes, you can get a specific html element with jQuery and use Ajax to request data from the server with PHP. PHP will query the MySQL database based on the form request made with Ajax and return the data retrieved from MySQL. jQuery will then be able to asign that data to the specific elements you want.

Comment: @nogad Not every question **must** contain code. This is a perfectly valid question about programming that can be answered objectively without writing half a book.

Comment: @icecub i look forward to your answer.

Comment: Question is - can this be done? -> Answer is: Yes! (But putting together a complete example with a database, PHP script, jQuery etc. is too broad IMHO)

Comment: @nogad I don't answer questions that I don't fully understand. Hence my comment above. SO isn't about nitpicking on every new member that is still learning the robes. A little friendlyness can go a long way. Especially if the question isn't "Do this for me", but "Is it possible, because I'm not sure if the language I'm trying to learn is the right one for my goal".

Comment: Thanks icecub; knowing that it can be done sets the wheels in motion so that one might break it down into smaller tasks and proceed from there - your answer is much appreciated.